# The specified processing_instruction is not supported for the given payment_source. PayPal hosted fields credit card payment

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to add credit card payment with hosted fields to my checkout. But I always get an UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY error within the Paypal JS SDK confirm-payment-source request.

I'm initiating the hosted field by adding this code:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?components=buttons,hosted-fields&client-id=<%= clientId %>" data-client-token="<%= clientToken %>"></script><div id="paypal-button-container" class="paypal-button-container"></div>
        <form id="card-form">
            <div id="card-number-field-container"></div>
            <div id="card-expiry-field-container"></div>
            <div id="card-cvv-field-container"></div>
            <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Pay Now</button>
        </form>

        <script>
        let orderId;
        paypal.HostedFields.render({
            createOrder: function () {
                orderId = "' . $_SESSION['ppcheckout_order_id'] . '";
                return orderId;
            },
            styles: {
                input: {
                    "font-size": "14px",
                    "font-family": "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                    "color": "#3a3a3a"
                },
                ":focus": {
                    "color": "blue"
                },
                ".valid": {
                    "color": "green"
                },
                ".invalid": {
                    "color": "red"
                }
            },
            fields: {
                number: {
                    selector: "#card-number-field-container",
                    placeholder: "Card Number"
                },
                expirationDate: {
                    selector: "#card-expiry-field-container",
                    placeholder: "MM/YY"
                },
                cvv: {
                    selector: "#card-cvv-field-container",
                    placeholder: "CVV"
                }
            }
        }).then(function (hostedFieldsInstance) {
            document.querySelector("#card-form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                hostedFieldsInstance.submit({
                    //contingencies: ["SCA_WHEN_REQUIRED"],
                    cardholderName: "Test Tester",
                    billigAddress: {
                        streetAddress: "123 Fake St",
                        postalCode: "04159",
                        region: "Saxonia",
                        locality: "Leipzig",
                        countryCodeAlpha2: "DE"
                    }
                }).then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

The fields will be rendered and working correctly.
But when I click on "Pay now", I get the following error:

```
{
    "name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "/processing_instruction",
            "value": "ORDER_COMPLETE_ON_PAYMENT_APPROVAL",
            "issue": "UNSUPPORTED_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION",
            "description": "The specified processing_instruction is not supported for the given payment_source. Please refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-processing_instruction for the list of payment_source that can be specified with this value."
        }
    ],
    "message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id": "f34205434abxx",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-UNSUPPORTED_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

It returns from a post call made by PayPals SDK: https://cors.api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/7DY53846GN90xxxx/confirm-payment-source

If I try it in postman, I get the same error.

I have absolutely no idea where the problem is. The credit card I used is generated by PayPals creditcard generator.

Does anyone has an idea?

Best,
Michael

Comment: You'll need to include an entire log (request and response) for creating the order_id

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from PayPal.
The creating order object must have `'processing_instruction': 'NO_INSTRUCTION'`. I used `'ORDER_COMPLETE_ON_PAYMENT_APPROVAL'` instead.

I've changed this and everything runs like a charm.